# Jquery open tab by url parimeter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, url, tabs

I am trying to make it so when a person enters a url like usercp.php#profile or usercp.php#settings, it will open to that tab. Another problem is, the tab href are all urls to different pages of the website. So basically, the code goes like this.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="usercptabs">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Account Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="usercp.php?action=profile">Customize Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="usercp.php?action=options">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="usercp.php?action=usergroups">Usergroups</a></li>
    <li><a href="usercp.php?action=editlists">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="usercp.php?action=drafts">Drafts</a></li>
    <li><a href="usercp.php?action=alert_settings">Alert Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="usercp.php?action=subscriptions">Thread Subscriptions</a></li>
  </ul>
```

How can this be done? I tried different solutions throughout stackoverflow, but they don't really work in this situation.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
      ui.panel.html('<center><img src="http://i.imgur.com/OZPnf**.gif" /></center>');
  }
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window.location` object holds all the information about the url, one property is `hash`.

So you could do something like the following that will trigger a click on the matching tab:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    /* your tab init code */    

    var hash = location.hash;
    if (hash && hash != '#') {
        hash=hash.substr(1); /* remove the "#" */
        $('#tabs a').filter(function () {
            return $(this).attr('href').indexOf(hash) > -1;
        }).click();/* click the matching tab */
    }
});
```

This solution assumes that the hashes that will be used will match the `action` param in query string of the url's. You have one that is a  match in question `profile` and one that is only close `settings`.  Additional refinement would be needed if they don't exactly match